# Mongoose finding record in a nested json and then update the array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I like to find a plan `purchasedPlans.plan` for a certain `user(email)` and then update its status to "Active"

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String ,    
    purchasedPlans:[{plan:String ,  status:String,}]
});
```

What is the code in Mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) `$`, like this:

```js
User.updateOne({
  "email": "user_email",
  "purchasedPlans.plan": "plan_to_change_status"
},{
  "$set": {
    "purchasedPlans.$.status": "Active"
  }
})
```

Comment: Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.